# Get the current item in ItemsControl MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I fill an `ItemsControl` with some keys list in a dictionary and I suggest to the user to map each key, printed in a `Label`, with some value in a `ComboBox` just below.

Finally, I have to get which Label key is corresponding by the selected value in the ComboBox in order to fill the dictionary values.

*All my controls are binded to the ViewModel properties, in a MVVM pattern.*

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="icMapping"
          HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxHeight="120"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ColumnsMapping}">

<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapPanel/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

<ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <ItemsPresenter/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ItemsControl.Template>

<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="6">
            <Label x:Name="lblPropertyKey"
                   Content="{Binding ApiPropertyKey}"
                   Width="250"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="cboxCsvHeaders"
                      Width="250"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                    AncestorType=Window},
                                    Path=DataContext.CsvTemplateFile.CsvHeaders}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding
                                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                                    AncestorType=Window},
                                    Path=DataContext.SelectedCsvHeader, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

I tried to loop through the `ItemsTemplate` in the `ItemsControl`, but I the `ComboBox`.Text is filled after binding the value in `SelectedItem`.

```
private string selectedCsvHeader;
public string SelectedCsvHeader
{
    get => selectedCsvHeader;
    set
    {
        selectedCsvHeader = value;
        if (value != null)
        {
            var ic = this.configView.icMapping;
            for (int i = 0; i < ic.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter cp = (System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter)ic.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(ic.Items[i]);
                System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox cbox = cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("cboxCsvHeaders", cp) as System.Windows.Controls.ComboBox;
                System.Windows.Controls.Label lbl = cp.ContentTemplate.FindName("lblPropertyKey", cp) as System.Windows.Controls.Label;

                MessageBox.Show((cbox.Text == selectedCsvHeader).ToString()); // False
            }
            FillDgPreview();
        }
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedCsvHeader));
    }
}
```

I used `ItemsControl` because I don't know in advance how much Keys I have in my dictionary. (After searching in the internet)
[Here an image to explain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKA1m.png)

Thanks advance!

Comment: ListBox is suitable for your task.
For what reason did you choose ItemsContol instead?

Comment: I agree with @EldHasp. With ListBox you have SelectedItem and SelectedValue.

Comment: First and foremost, you're breaking the MVVM pattern if you're using the controls from the view in your view model. The point of the View Model is designed to be an abstraction of the view. 

Secondly, It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. Maybe using dictionaries is not the best solution to your problem. You shouldn't need to iterate through each of your items.

Try a class for your CSV file, and then make a class for your CSV header. Make a Collection of your CSV header class in your file class. Then add that CSV file model to a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to set the values of the entries of a dictionary you would have to use a dictionary class that allows to change the `Value` property of its Key/Value pair entries.

Since `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>` does not allow that (because `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is immutable), you could write your own dictionary class, probably more sophisticated than in this example:

```
public class KeyValue
{
    public KeyValue(string key, string value = null)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Key { get; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<KeyValue> Map { get; } = new List<KeyValue>();

    public List<string> Keys { get; } = new List<string>();
}
```

You would now bind that view model as in the XAML shown below, where `{Binding Key}` and `{Binding Value}` use the dictionary entry (i.e. a `Map` collection element) as source object. These binding would look different in case you were using a custom dictionary class with a different entry type.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Map}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
                <ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding Value}"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.Keys,
                                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ItemsControl}}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```